# How to define project.clj for both lein run and lein repl to work?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure, and I don't quite understand how to write my `project.clj` so it works for both `lein repl` and `lein run`. Here it is (whole path: `~/my-project/project.clj`):

```
(defproject my-project "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
  :main my-project.core/hello
)
```

Then I have my `~/my-project/src/my_project/core.clj` file

```
(ns my-project.core)

(defn hello []
  (println "Hello world!")
)
```

`lein run` works just fine but I get a `FileNotFoundException` when running `lein repl`:

```
~/my-project$ lein run
Hello world!
~/my-project$ lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 42144
FileNotFoundException Could not locate hello__init.class or hello.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:430)
clojure.core=>
```

How should I edit the `project.clj` to solve this? Or do I have to call `lein repl` in a different way?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: tried with `lein dep`s and `lein compile`, but still the same error

```
~/my-project$ lein version
Leiningen 1.7.1 on Java 1.6.0_27 OpenJDK Client VM
~/my-project$ lein deps
Copying 1 file to /home/yasin/Programming/Clojure/my-project/lib
~/my-project$ lein compile
No namespaces to :aot compile listed in project.clj.
~/my-project$ lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 41945
FileNotFoundException Could not locate hello__init.class or hello.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:430)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using lein 1, right? (You can check with `lein version`). In this case I think you should first run `lein deps` and `lein compile` and then try with `lein repl`.

Comment: Thanks, but still no go... I've edited the question with more details.

Comment: @m0skit0 If you're new to clojure, use lein2. There should be no reason to use lein 1.7 at this point, especially not if you're just starting out.

Comment: @Cubic Thank you. I didn't even know there are a lein2. I just installed it from Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @m0skit0 I'd suggest you to skip those for all things you use directly. It's not true for all of them, but a great deal of the packages are quite dated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One thing you could do to get it to work would be to change `core.clj` to:

```
(ns my-project.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn hello []
  (println "Hello world!"))

(defn -main []
  (hello))
```

And edit the `project.clj` to:

```
(defproject my-project "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
  :main my-project.core)
```

The `(:gen-class)` will tell the compiler to generate a Java class for the namespace, and the `:main` directive in `project.clj` will tell `lein run` to run the main method on the class, which is given by `-main`.  Why `lein repl` was failing to find `my-project.core/hello` is unclear to me, but I don't know much about leiningen internals.

Comment: It works. I only have to define a `-main` function for it to work and change the :main to `:main my-project.core` as you suggest. Btw you forgot a parenthesis at the end of `core.clj`, I fixed it :)

Comment: why does leiningen need the main in a jar, for firing up a repl actually?